# Passing a dynamic variable in an array within PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am not sure if it's possible or not but I am trying to pass a random variable to fill an array.

Here is the code normally:-

```
//Loading all data of user in an array variable.
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
// Updated one array variable in this array.
$user_fields -> field_module_3_status['und'][0]['value'] = "Started";
// Saved back the updated user data
user_save($user_fields);
```

But I want to provide the variable `field_module_3_status` dynamically through a variable.

Hence suppose I have `$user_field_name = field_module_3_status`.

So what I tried to do is:-

```
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);

$this_users_status = $user_fields -> $user_field_name;

$this_users_status['und'][0]['value'] = "Started";

user_save($user_fields);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: `$val; $ref =& $val; $val = 0; /*ref is 0 now*/ $val = 't'; /*ref is 't' now*/` this could help you along your path. EDIT: reversed &=

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried something like this and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a copy of the array when you do the assignment to `$this_users_status`. You need to assign to the array in the object property.

```
$user_fields->{$user_field_name}['und'][0]['value'] = "Started";
```

Or you could use a reference:

```
$this_users_status =& $user_fields->$user_field_name;
```